# Checking if received JSON contains specific values in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm having the following situation:
I'm getting information about a game in JSON.
There are multiple players in that game, with multiple items.

The player code looks like this:

```
$playerOne   = $json->games[$i]->fellowPlayers[0];
$playerTwo   = $json->games[$i]->fellowPlayers[1];
$playerThree = $json->games[$i]->fellowPlayers[2];
$playerFour  = $json->games[$i]->fellowPlayers[3];
$playerFive  = $json->games[$i]->fellowPlayers[4];
$playerSeven = $json->games[$i]->fellowPlayers[6];
$playerEight = $json->games[$i]->fellowPlayers[7];
$playerNine  = $json->games[$i]->fellowPlayers[8];
```

$i is a var from my for loop. I didnt add the rest of the code becuase it isn't needed.

So here is what i'm trying to solve. not all players and items slots are always filled. So i need a way to check if they are in the JSON.

I tried:

```
if(!is_null($json->games[$i]->fellowPlayers[5])){
    $playerSix = $json->games[$i]->fellowPlayers[5];
}
```

But that didn't work.
Ty in advance

Comment: have you tried "empty($json->games[$i]->fellowPlayers[5])" ?

Comment: can you show [var_dump](http://ir1.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)  of your **$json**

Comment: I don't believe it will be `null`. Can you echo the value `$json->games[$i]->fellowPlayers[5]`, is it not an empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!empty($json->games[$i]->fellowPlayers[0])){

    $playerOne = $json->games[$i]->fellowPlayers[0];

}
```

that worked.

answer by: sHentschel

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($json->games[$i]->fellowPlayers[5]))
{
    $playerSix = $json->games[$i]->fellowPlayers[5];
}
```

you check if the array member with such index exists and then assign it to a variable. You can also do any additional check needed.